# Updating a button id

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to update an id with a value from another button, here's what I have up to now:

```
$('.viewemployment').on('click', function(e){
    var url = '<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>dashboard/employment_json/' + this.id;
    $.get(url,function(d){
            document.getElementById("update_employment").value = this.id;
        },'json');
    });
```

The above is working, because the rest of my code (which I have removed) is working, but the set value isn't. This is the button I am trying to set a value to the id

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default waves-effect update_employment" id="update_employment"  style="display: none;"><?php echo System::translate("Update Employment"); ?></button>
```

I want to use the id of this button for an ajax request:

```
    $('.update_employment').on('click', function(e){
        $.ajax({
          url: "<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>/dashboard/update_employment/" + $("input[name='json_name']").val() + "/" + 
                $("#json_country").find(":selected").text() + "/" + $("input[name='json_start']").val() + "/" + $("input[name='json_end']").val()
                + "/" + $("input[name='json_duration']").val() + "/" + $("input[name='json_description']").val() + "/" + this.id  + "/" + "<?php echo System::escape(Session::get('token')); ?>",
          cache: false,
          success: function(html){
            <!-- success !-->
          }
        });
```

but the this.id is being passed as update_employment rather than the new value which shouldv'e been set

Comment: id and value are different properties. Are you sure you want to change the id of an element? Instead of 'this.id' in your second piece of code, maybe something like '$(this).val()'?

Comment: Yup want to change the id value so in my ajax request I can use it with this.id

Comment: If you change the id, I think that might affect the way your click function works, which is why I'm suggesting you take the value instead (since that's what you're setting anyway).
If you REALLY want to try using the id, try changing the following line:
document.getElementById("update_employment").value = this.id;
to:
document.getElementById("update_employment").id = this.id;

Comment: @Eraph, create an answer with that and I'll accept as best answer as it worked, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the following line:
    document.getElementById("update_employment").value = this.id;
to:
    document.getElementById("update_employment").id = this.id;

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a good idea to change the `id`, because you can soon lose track of it as the complexity of you app increases. Instead, you could capture the value of `this.id` to a variable and store it using jQuery's [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) function:

```
$('.viewemployment').on('click', function(e){
    var theId = this.id;
    var url = '<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>dashboard/employment_json/' + theId;
    $.get(url,function(d){
            $("#update_employment").data("idToQuery", theId);
        },'json');
    });
```

Then access it with:

```
$("#update_employment").data("idToQuery")
```

If you really must change the button's `id`, you can do it through jQuery's [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function:

```
$('#update_employment').attr('id', theId)
```

Comment: Still doesn't seem to be updating the id value, I check my debug tab on chrome and the vlaue's still being sent as update_employment

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the target's id from the Event. `e` is an [`Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event)

```
$('.viewemployment').on('click', function(e){
    var url = '<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>dashboard/employment_json/' + this.id;
    $.get(url,function(d){
        document.getElementById("update_employment").value = e.target.id;
    },'json');
});
```